# How to include Net-SNMP to QT project

Tags: qt, net-snmp

I'm trying to run this project:
https://github.com/vanhsati/SNMP-Monitor
Downloaded net-SNMP from:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/net-snmp/files/latest/download
I get a lot of errors when I try to build project.
Example code from official net-SNMP wiki also includes only two ".h" files.
How can I properly link the library to QT creator?

Comment: See how to do same thing with any C++ project using CMake. And then use CMake with your Qt project. Realize how to do Qt with CMake as well. I am very sure.

Comment: I'm asking because I can't find. The compiler complains about redefining lots of stuctures.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with Qt but with C++ and why and what unclear at all. Maybe you do not have that library installed maybe the package not found. We cannot guess.